# Creating new component from existing without losing history

Tags: rtc, rational-team-concert

Due to poor planning, I have created multiple projects as sub folders under one component and it's been an year.
Now we want to divide that component into multiple new components without loosing the history of each project.
I have only option to create new component or to add an existing component in RTC. Is there a way to create a new component from an existing component without losing history?